# I need to insert value to input-textbox using jQuery and increment value if already exists.

Tags: jquery, html, css

1. Insert a value (integer value) to input-textbox.
2. if a value is already in the input field than do addition.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: `Insert a value (integer value) to input-textbox`, any particular integer value, or just a random one?

Comment: I have a button and on-click I need to add a value to the text-field but if there is a value in the text-field than there needs to be addition.

Comment: new to jQuery ;)

Comment: Start reading the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) first and then update your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing this:

```
var value = $('#input_id').val();
$('#input_id').val(value ? ++value : yourValue);
```

Comment: It's a good tradition to mark answer which helped with green mark )))